# New column in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm starting in Python and I have a question. I have the next data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['Jon', 'Mike', 'Angel', 'Brenda'], 'Action':['walk', 'run', 'walk', 'jump']})

 print(df)
 # Output: 
 #    names   Action
 # 0    Jon     walk
 # 1   Mike      run
 # 2  Angel     walk
 # 3 Brenda     jump
```

And I would like that any time that Action is walk in a new column take the name in the next row

i.e.

```
 # Output: 
 #    names   Action    newcolumn
 # 0    Jon     walk         Mike   
 # 1   Mike      run 
 # 2  Angel     walk       Brenda
 # 3 Brenda     jump
```

I'm trying with the next code but not work on it, it fill all time Mike

```
df.loc[:, "Columna 3"] = df.loc[df'Action'] == 'walk','names'].iloc[1]
```

Comment: you cannot generalize iloc[1] as it will pick Mike. You need to iterate through the df to check for value and pick the previous row.

Comment: That's because you specified using the value from row 1 for every such action.  You need to specify "next row", not row 1.

Comment: Could you help me how can I do? I'm new in python

Comment: See my response if that helps solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output, I think here's what you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'names': ['Jon', 'Mike', 'Angel', 'Brenda'], 'Action':['walk','run','walk','jump']})

print (df)

df['newcolumn'] = df.loc[df['Action'].shift(1)== 'walk', 'names']
df['newcolumn'] = df['newcolumn'].shift(-1).fillna('')

print (df)
```

The original df:

```
    names Action
0     Jon   walk
1    Mike    run
2   Angel   walk
3  Brenda   jump
```

The updated df with newcolumn:

```
    names Action newcolumn
0     Jon   walk      Mike
1    Mike    run          
2   Angel   walk    Brenda
3  Brenda   jump
```

Comment: If the answer resolved your problem statement, dont forget to upvote and flag as answered.